# Spring boot addResourceHandlers not working on linux

Tags: spring-boot

In my spring boot application, I am adding resource handlers via the below method. Handler is added to the location on windows setup, however are not being done so when deployed on my linux machine.

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    //linux
    registry.addResourceHandler("/content/**").addResourceLocations("file:/app/content/").setCachePeriod(0);

    //windows
    //registry.addResourceHandler("/content/**").addResourceLocations("file:/D:\files\").setCachePeriod(0);
}
```

NOTE: The target folder on the linux machine has read write permissions as well. Also, have tried with file:// and file:///

Any other settings that I might be missing. Access to the files on http://myhost/content/file.jpg result in 404 on linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved. Issue was with the apache proxy conf.
Initially I was serving the static files via apache. Later was doing so from within the spring boot application.
However,

ProxyPassMatch ^/content !

this setting was still there  the conf which was not forwarding the requests to the interceptor.